# How Does Time Machine Check for "Runtime Corruption" and How Do I Reset It?

Tags: network, backup, time-machine, mojave, nas

After working quite happily for months, Time Machine running with a NAS as a backup destination has suddenly decided that my backup is "corrupt" after failing a check for "runtime corruption" and is insisting that I must delete the entire (4 terabyte) backup and start again!

What I want to know is how Time Machine determines "runtime corruption", and can I in some way reset or disable this check?

I have already checked the disk image itself using the following commands:

```
hdiutil attach -nomount /Volumes/Path/To/Backup.sparsebundle
diskutil verifyDisk diskN
diskutil verifyVolume diskNs2
```

Substituting paths and disk numbers where appropriate, and have found no errors whatsoever. So what exactly is Time Machine checking?

I've also checked almost all of the most recent backup (using `shasum`, ignoring files with newer modified times) and everything is fine; I can't find any evidence that anything is corrupted in any way, certainly not any of the files I care about most.

It's laughable really, as the only processes to touch the bundle are Time Machine and related components, there has been no sign of any kind of network connectivity issue, no other errors in the logs, and every other backup for the same day was completed without issue. Which means that any "runtime corruption" is most likely the fault of Time Machine itself!

It's also even more ridiculous that the only option presented is to wipe everything, rather than perform a deep traversal to compare the contents in detail (to find anything that may indeed be corrupted and replace it, not that I believe there is any corruption at all).

I don't want to have to discard 4 terabytes of backups for some vague, unspecified "corruption" that doesn't even appear to exist, so is there some way I can remove whatever data Time Machine is using to detect its mythical "runtime corruption" (a check it doesn't even appear to do with direct attached drives) so that I can just continue backing up?

**EDIT**:
So I've gained some new information, which is that the Time Machine "runtime corruption" check is actually just running `fsck_hfs -q`, which has nothing to do with corruption whatsoever, it is merely a test of whether a disk image was unmounted "uncleanly", which is no guarantee of corruption (as I have already confirmed).

Unfortunately despite managing to clear the "inconsistent" bit (which indicates an unclean unmount) using `fsck_hfs -p` time machine is still refusing to use this backup, despite the runtime corruption check no longer failing. Meaning some other data must be stored somewhere.

Comment: Could you check your system.log in Console.app to see if you have any messages regarding the Time Machine drive? Looks for read/write errors, I/O errors, HFS errors, etc. It might be that further details are listed in the log.

Comment: @jksoegaard I've already tried the logs and there's no sign of errors; just a successful backup at 3pm, then at 4pm it checks for "runtime corruption" and decides to never backup ever again. Like I say, I've verified the disk image, and checked the latest backup (I've also checksummed most of the large files), and there's no sign of any corruption. What I need is to know how to override the "runtime corruption" check as I don't trust its accuracy nor want its fallback behaviour (delete everything).

Comment: The `fsck_hfs -q` likely reads a status to show that that volume was previously marked as suspect or if the actual check has caught corruption. If a simple unclean mount killed backups we would have 100 tickets each morning with forever broken Time Machine - in a lab, we've beat on this repeatedly and the only implementation that seems more fragile is network. Use a direct attach disk if you can't afford to lose a backup set would be my main advice, but that's not really what's being asked here. I'll see if there's a different question covering that and link here if I find one.

Comment: @bmike: Thanks for the response, but I do have a direct attached backup as well, the network backup is intended to be a secondary backup in case that one fails (or a surge takes out both the computer and its direct backup). Unfortunately the `fsck_hfs -q` doesn't appear to be the entire story, as after removing the inconsistent flag Time Machine is still refusing to backup.

Comment: I had the same problem, multiple times with different external disks. I share your analysis, and thanks for the detailed solution you added!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've now discovered a complete solution by (carefully) following these steps:

1. Turn off Time Machine's automatic backups in the Time Machine preference pane (to prevent any conflicts).
2. First mount the network volume to which Time Machine is backing up, how to do this will depend upon your system, there should be a disk image in there named after your computer (e.g- for a system named "Haravikk's Mac Mini" you'll find "Haravikk's Mac Mini.sparsebundle"
3. Attach the image using the following command in Terminal.app: `hdiutil attach -readwrite -nomount /path/to/image` (you can fill in the path by dragging onto a terminal window from the finder, just make sure there's a space after `-nomount`).
4. Take a note of the device numbers returned, one of these will be your backup volume, usually the last one in the form of `diskNs2` where `N` is the disk number, and the s2 should be the partition.
5. Run the following command, taking note to add `r` to the start of the device number to connect to the "raw" (unbuffered) device: `fsck_hfs -p /dev/rdiskNs2`
6. Wait for the check to finish; if it finds any errors it should attempt to fix them then run again automatically, wait for the process to finish. If it reports there were errors that could not be fixed then you should consider discarding the backups as recommended, or else run the command again with `-f` instead of `-p` (though this is not recommended).
7. At this point you should really check that your latest backup isn't corrupt; you can do this visually by mounting the image (`diskutil mount diskNs2` substituting as appropriate) and examining in the Finder. A more detailed comparison is recommended however but beyond the scope of this answer.
8. Detach the disk image with the following command (substituting disk ID): `hdiutil detach diskN` (if you mounted the image above, "eject" it first).
9. In the Finder open the the folder with your backup disk image, right-click it and choose "Show Contents". Inside you'll find a file called `com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist`, open it. If you have Xcode installed it will open in this, otherwise you should be able to open it in TextEdit; when editing in TextEdit you'll need to have some familiarity with XML and plist files, though they're pretty straightforward.
10. Find the `VerificationState` key and change its value to `1` (it will probably be set to `2` if you're experiencing the same issue as me).
11. Find the `RecoveryBackupDeclinedDate` key and delete it, if you're using TextEdit make sure you also delete its `<date>` value.
12. Save your changes, unmount the network volume and re-enable Time Machine's automatic backups.
13. Either wait for the next backup, or run one immediately; if your network destination isn't your only backup device you can trigger a backup to it in the Time Machine preference pane by right-clicking on the destination's icon and choosing "Back up to  now".

#### Details

It seems that Time Machine's "runtime corruption" check is a call to a `fsck_hfs -q`, which checks whether a volume was unmounted uncleanly. If this fails, the volume will have an "inconsistent" bit set against it that can only be cleared by successfully repairing it using `fsck_hfs -p` or similar.

However, in addition to this Time Machine stores a "corrupt" status in its `com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist` within the disk image bundle. I'm kicking myself for not finding this sooner since it's right there just inside it. I'm not sure if Time Machine performs any additional checks, there is a key related to some kind of extended check, but I'm not sure exactly what this entails.

Correcting both restores the image to "normal" status, allowing Time Machine to run without issue.

**NOTE**: While in my case the "runtime corruption" check was definitely mistaken, it is important that you check whether there is any actual corruption to ensure this is the case. It's a bit beyond the scope of this answer to cover that as well, but if anyone would like to recommend tools or guides for doing so please comment!

#### Extra

I ended up finding these solutions myself despite trying to get help from Apple engineers; they just wasted my time trying to find ways to blame me for the fault, rather than telling me what I needed to know, and they've gone and closed my bug report despite my having shown them exactly how I verified no corruption had occurred!

Very, **very** disappointed with Apple's handling of a report that their flagship backup tool may be deleting users' backups unnecessarily. I'm now seriously considering ditching Time Machine entirely next time I upgrade my storage, as I'm no longer confident I can trust it, or the engineers who work on it, and may go for the overkill option of something based on ZFS send.

Answer (score 1):

After following the instructions, I wasn't able to run `fsck_hfs` because I lacked permissions, even as root. The `fsck` only ran after changing the sparsebundle's permissions and mounting it with readwrite access

```
chflags -R nouchg /Volumes/xyz.sparsebundle
hdiutil attach -nomount -readwrite /Volumes/xyz.sparsebundle
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this once, I deleted the drive from the Time Machine settings and added it again. Your system will then check everything and make a new backup.

Comment: You'll note that the OP was asking specifically how to avoid recreating the backup.  You do not answer that question.

Comment: @MarcWilson Removing the drive from the Time Machine preferences, then re-adding it does not create a new backup. Instead, it should inherit the existing one and continue backing up to it.

Comment: Except that the existing one was already marked as corrupted.